# Why do I get a popup saying hardware configuration has changed?

Tags: hardware, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Sometimes when I start Modern Warfare 2 on my Windows 10 laptop, i get a popup asking me if I want to set optimal settings because my hardware configuration changed since the last time I played. If I press yes, my resolution drops, the game takes up 1/4th of my screen... Why do I get the popup if I dont change anything with my hardware and why does the resolution drop if I select "Yes"?

Comment: Do you perhaps switch monitors at times?

Comment: I don't, it's always the same 1920x1080 laptop display.

Comment: Do you have any other hardware you regularly change (keyboard, controller, mouse)? Do you get these messages every single time you start up the game?

Comment: Sometimes I play with headphones, sometimes without. I dont change anything else. Yesterday I clicked yes to see what would happen and after that I didnt get the message, but before that I usually did.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with your configuration getting reset.

**Try setting the file *config_mp.cfg* to 'Read-only'**. This file contains your user settings, and can be found in *Steam\steamapps\common\MW2\Players*.
<kbd>Right-click</kbd> the file, select 'Properties', and select (or deselect) the '*Read-only*' flag (if it's *Read-only* already, it might not save your custom changes; if it's not *Read-only* yet, they might get overwritten by the default settings every time the game starts up).

If this doesn't yield the desired results, you might want to [check other files](https://www.reddit.com/r/modernwarfare/comments/dosv4s/settings_does_not_save_on_pc_please_help/) in that same folder for the same flag.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution drop is a common bug, probably they added wrong configurations in default game settings, I get that message every time I perform a driver update, when I create a virtual device (VirtualBox VGA maybe, or RTX Voice virtual microphone), or even when I change overclock profile.